# Symfony - is there a way to set a entity global?

Tags: php, symfony, shopware6

I have a entity which i extend on a login page but on the next page the extension does not exist (The Entity does on both pages). Is there a way to make my extension available on the next page?

```
<?php
namespace RegistrationExtension\Subscriber;

use ...

class RegisterExtensionSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface{
    private $company;

    /**
     * @var EntityRepositoryInterface
     */
    private $mailTypeRepository;

    /**
     * @var EntityRepositoryInterface
     */
    private $mailRepository;
    /**
     * @var EntityRepositoryInterface
     */
    private $customerRepo;

    public function __construct(
        EntityRepositoryInterface $customerRepo,
        EntityRepositoryInterface $mailTypeRepository,
        EntityRepositoryInterface $mailRepository
    ) {
        $this->customerRepo = $customerRepo;
         $this->mailTypeRepository = $mailTypeRepository;
         $this->mailRepository = $mailRepository;
    }
    public static function getSubscribedEvents(): array{
        return [
            AccountLoginPageLoadedEvent::class => 'extendCustomer',
            AccountOverviewPageLoadedEvent::class => 'onCustomRegister'
        ];
    }
```

This functions triggers when the logged in page finished loading.

```
    public function extendCustomer(AccountLoginPageLoadedEvent $event){
       // if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
            if(isset($_GET["email"])){
                $company = $_GET["email"];
            }else{
                $company = null;
            }
            $mailEntity = $this->mailTypeRepository->search(
                (new Criteria())->addFilter(new EqualsFilter('mail_template_type.technicalName', "customer_register")),
                $event->getContext()
            );
    
            if ($mailType = $mailEntity->getEntities()->first()) {
                $mailEntity = $this->mailRepository->search(
                    (new Criteria())->addFilter(new EqualsFilter('mail_template.mailTemplateTypeId', $mailType->getId())),
                    $event->getContext()
                );
            
                $mailEntity->getEntities()->first()->addExtension('file_does_exist', new ArrayEntity(['company' => "blub"]));
                dump($mailEntity->getEntities()->first());
            }
       // }
    }
```

This functions triggers after the user has logged in and the page finished loading.

```
    public function onCustomRegister(AccountOverviewPageLoadedEvent $event){
        $mailEntity = $this->mailTypeRepository->search(
            (new Criteria())->addFilter(new EqualsFilter('mail_template_type.technicalName', "customer_register")),
            $event->getContext()
        );

        if ($mailType = $mailEntity->getEntities()->first()) {
            $mailEntity = $this->mailRepository->search(
                (new Criteria())->addFilter(new EqualsFilter('mail_template.mailTemplateTypeId', $mailType->getId())),
                $event->getContext()
            );
            dump($mailEntity);
          //  $mail = $mailEntity->getEntities()->first()->addExtension('file_does_exist', new ArrayEntity(['company' => $company]));
        }
        $customerEntity = $this->customerRepo->search(
            (new Criteria())->addFilter(new EqualsFilter('customer.customerNumber', $event->getSalesChannelContext()->getCustomer()->getCustomerNumber())),
            $event->getContext()
        );         
    }
}
```

Could it be that the AccountOverviewPageLoadedEvent event loads beo?

Comment: if you have an entity which you load and extend only once per logged-in session - why not using the session to keep that entity?

Comment: Hey, thanks for your reply. Actually it is a registration form. So the customer does not exist until finished the registration process.  My main goal is that the customer while filling the registration form can upload a file. this files in this case here is than a extension. After that i want to make it available on a mail entity to send the information per mail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you already discovered while devloping, extensions aren't persisted.
What you would want is an [EntityExtension](https://docs.shopware.com/en/shopware-platform-dev-en/how-to/entity-extension). This way you can extend the customer entity. However since only association and foreign key fields can get added via a EntityExtension, you would need a own entity.

So let's assume you [create a entity](https://docs.shopware.com/en/shopware-platform-dev-en/how-to/indepth-guide-bundle/entity): CustomerRegistrationFile
You could then extend the CustomerDefinition and add your CustomerRegistrationFile as an association. This way you can persist data directly at the entity and can load it everywhere you need it for example in your mail template.

Side note: Associations aren't auto loaded. Except for OneToOneAssociations can be auto loaded from one end. Not both end's, to prevent circular references.

Comment: Ah ok, instead of extending the existing entity i need a new to make the data persist? :D

Comment: You need to differ between extensions and a EntityExtension. Every entity in shopware can be enriched with an extension like you did, those arent persisted. If you create an EntityExtension where you add your own entity, you create a structural change. And those changes can and will get persisted.